# How to get rid of python manage.py permission denied problem in Vs code?

Tags: python, django, windows-10

I tried to run command "python manage.py runserver" in VS code but i always get this message:

> bash: /c/Users/ACER/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied

[Python permission denied picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcLXZ.png)

And also, i tried to run command "py manage.py runserver" still it does not run, instead it says:

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

[py manage.py runserver pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeyZn.png)

Comment: (a) Have you installed Python? How? (b) You seem to be running via a Mingw bash shell. Why?

Answer (score 0):

VScode just runs on top of Windows Powershell, so it is not related to VScode, it is probably your python installation.

This is a quick [tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-windows) on installing python, take a look on step 6 as is guides you to setup PATH variables. Also, using virtualenv would solve this issue and is a good practice.